# Module Exceptions in Angularjs and $exceptionHandler

Tags: javascript, angularjs, exception

In the documentation of Angular 1 for `$exceptionHandler` it says:

> Any uncaught exception in angular expressions is delegated to this service.

https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/docs/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler

Yet when I get a module initialisation error (`Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to: ...`) it does not seem to get logged via the $exceptionHandler.

I want to be able to log these Errors to Sentry via Raven and am having trouble finding a solution to this.

This is an example of what i am trying to achieve:

```js
// Main App module
angular.module('app', ['app.welcome', 'app.contact'])
    .factory('$exceptionHandler', [function() {
        return function myExceptionHandler(exception, cause) {
           // why does the module initialisation error not get caught here..?
           console.log("[ERROR] ", exception.message);
        };
     }]);

// a module I forgot to load..
// app.module('app.contact', []);

// another sub module
angular.
module('app.welcome', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {
    $scope.test = function() {
      $window.alert('test');
    };
  }]);
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="ExampleController">
 <button ng-click="test()">Test</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet which raise an error because `$q` is not injected, do whatever you want in custom exception handler.

```js
angular.module('app', []);

angular.
module('app')
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.test = function() {
      $q.when("foo");
    };
  }])
  .factory('$exceptionHandler', [function() {
    return function myExceptionHandler(exception, cause) {
      console.log("[ERROR] ", exception.message);
    };
  }]);
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="ExampleController">
 <button ng-click="test()">Raise Error</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am trying to catch the errors of failed module initialisation however, if, for example I require a module which I forgot to load.  I added a snippet which demonstrates the behaviour.